# python speed composed functions

Tags: python, performance

I'd like to understand why I get the speed differences that I see when I compose functions in different ways.
I'm mostly interested in understanding why case (1) is faster than case (2).

Thanks!

```
import math
from time import time

def f(x):
    return 2*x
def g(x):
    return x*x
def h(x):
    return math.sqrt(x)

time0 = time()
for x in range(1,10**7):
    x_ = h(g(f(x)))
print 'h(g(f(x))): {}'.format( time() - time0)

def fgh(x):
    return h(g(f(x)))
time0 = time()
for x in range(1,10**7):
    x_ = fgh(x)
print 'composed: {}'.format( time() - time0)

time0 = time()
for x in range(1,10**7):
    x_ = f(x)
    x__ = g(x_)
    x___ = h(x__)
print 'subsequent: {}'.format( time() - time0)
```

As runtimes, I get:

```
h(g(f(x))): 2.83475399017
composed: 3.29999113083
subsequent: 3.4387819767
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, case 2 has one extra call - that of `fgh(x)`, whereas in case 1 you're calling `h(g(f(x)))` directly. Inside a tight loop that gets executed many times, that additional function call can add extra execution time. Case 1 in-lines that call, so it's a bit faster. Case 3 is doing some extra assignments and loading variables, which explains why it's slower.

Comment: OK, I thought something like that. Is it fair to say that if each of the composed functions is more complex and time intensive, it doesn't matter for the runtime how I compose them? (i.e. the additional function call in example 2 becomes negligible)

Comment: For the general case, it depends on the function - there might be situations where the composition order _does_ matter (for instance: when composing the multiplication of large matrices). For your example it might not matter that much, but one can assume that operations such as taking the square root will be slower for larger numbers, so it'll be slightly slower if we leave it for the end